# GitLab API - How to know names of removed merged branches

Tags: git, api, gitlab, gitlab-api

GitLab allows you deleting merged branches by running

`curl --request DELETE --header "PRIVATE-TOKEN: 9koXpg98eAheJpvBs5tK" https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/5/repository/merged_branches`

but doesn't return any information except status code.

How can I know which branches was deleted by this request?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there's no way to know from that request. A work around I recently created was to grab all the merged branches before you delete them:

```
public function getAllMergedFeatures() : array
{
    $merge_requests = $this->call("GET",
        "{$this->basePath}/merge_requests?state=merged"
    );

    return array_column($merge_requests, 'source_branch');
}
```

That will give you an array of all the branches that have been merged.

Here's the call method I use:

```
    public function call(string $method, string $path, array $params = [])
    {
        try {
            return json_decode(
                $this->client->request(
                    $method,
                    $path,
                    array_merge(
                        $this->getHeaders(),
                        ['form_params' => $params]
                    )
                )->getBody()
            );
        } catch(Exception $e) {
            return $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

After you call the delete method you can do a check to see if they were all removed or w/e you want to do. Also, if your feature branches are merged into more than one branch they will show up multiple times in the array. Be sure to account for that.

Good luck, hope this helps.